# Ember abort - how to prevent from forward transition

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I am looking a solution to prevent my `forward` transition from `abort`. I just want  to prevent the back button ( previous page ) transition after mid of a page. how to do that?

here is my try :

```
willTransition:function( transition ){

            var target = transition.targetName;

            let previousTransition = this.controllerFor(this.routeName).get('previousTransition.targetName');

            console.log( target, 'previousTransition', previousTransition );

            if(this.get('modelProvider').get('cardTxnPage') === true &&  previousTransition ){
                transition.abort();
            }
        },
```

In above all are correct. But even I am not able to proceed to next page. means it abort prevents both forward/backward by condition.

any one show me the right approach?

Comment: Can you try and clarify a little more? Do you want to disable the back button after the page is scrolled to some distance?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```js
window.location.hash="no-back-button";
window.location.hash="Again-No-back-button";
window.onhashchange=function(){window.location.hash="no-back-button";}
```